# Different learning rate affect to batchnorm setting. Why?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am using BatchNorm layer. I know the meaning of setting `use_global_stats` that often set `false` for training and `true` for testing/deploy. This is my setting in the testing phase.

```
layer {
  name: "bnorm1"
  type: "BatchNorm"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "bnorm1"
  batch_norm_param {
    use_global_stats: true
  }
}
layer {
  name: "scale1"
  type: "Scale"
  bottom: "bnorm1"
  top: "bnorm1"
  bias_term: true
  scale_param {
    filler {
      value: 1
    }    
    bias_filler {
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
```

In solver.prototxt, I used the Adam method. I found an interesting problem that happens in my case. If I choose `base_lr: 1e-3`, then I got a good performance when I set `use_global_stats: false` in the testing phase. However, if I chose `base_lr: 1e-4`, then I got a good performance when I set `use_global_stats: true` in the testing phase. It demonstrates that `base_lr` effects to the batchnorm setting (even I used Adam method)? Could you suggest any reason for that? Thanks all

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK learning rate does not *directly* affect the learned parameters of `"BatchNorm"` layer. Indeed, caffe forces `lr_mult` for all internal parameters of this layer to be zero regardless of `base_lr` or the `type` of the solver.
However, you might encounter a case where the adjacent layers converge to different points according to the `base_lr` you are using, and indirectly this causes the `"BatchNorm"` to behave differently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `the adjacent layers converge to different points ` means the local optimal. Is it right? If it right, maybe the learning rate is too small

Comment: @KimHee usually with `"Adam"` solver one tends to set `base_lr` a bit higher relative to other solvers.

Comment: Do you think Adam solver is always better for all networks in comparison with SGD?

Comment: @KimHee I don;t think I'm qualified to answer such question.